# Java extend arraylist with list of n values

Tags: java, python, list, arraylist, extend

In python I can do the following:

```
n = 8  
a = []  
a += [1]*n
```

How can I do the equivalent in java with ArrayLists (without using a for loop..)?

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
// Some construct that is equivalent to a += [1]*n
```

Comment: For adding a list to the first one: [`List.addAll(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: Sure, but that list does not exist yet. Collections.nCopies(8, 1) does what i want :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.addAll(Collections.nCopies(8, 1));
```

see [`Collections.nCopies()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies%28int,%20T%29)